# How do you kasher your teeth?

Tags: passover, parts-of-the-body, kashering-kosherization, cleaning, teeth

A Pesach preparation guide tells me to [kasher my teeth](http://shulchanaruchharav.com/Home-Database/docs/Pesach%20Checklist.pdf) on Erev Pesach.

How on earth does one do this?

Comment: By brushing them to make sure crumbs of hametz are gone?

Comment: R Moshe Bick IINM, when a questioner insisted he wanted the "real" answer and not just Kulas, instructed someone to pour boiling water in his mouth, and "when you start screaming, it's kosher".

Comment: Hachay eino bolea but prothesis yes. Kebolo Kach polto. The  or coffee warm and waiting 24 h without warm hamets.

Comment: The real question is what to use for false teeth or fillings. This is not a pesach shaala but one for the whole year since you  eat milk and meat with them.  One should use a material that is not "bolea".  In other words not metal teeth.  A mouth doesnt always use "klai shaini" since it sometimes eats a "gush" which is treated like "klai rishon". I think the munkats darkai tshuva discusses this

Comment: It is downright irresponsible for a practical guide to say "kasher your teeth" without elaboration.

Comment: @newcomer I have heard someone suggest that people who wear braces need to use *libun* to kasher their braces. I guess it couldn't be much worse than when Moshe ate the hot coals as a kid. At the end of the day, he still spoke a lot.

Comment: OK. It just occurred to me ... do they mean false teeth, aka dentures? If so, that can most likely be koshered by soaking them in Polident.

Comment: Definitely glad to be Sephardic

Comment: @DanF I shudder to think of where in the frum world "teeth" automatically means "false teeth"

Comment: @SAH Perhaps you haven't been around that many Jewish old people? I often hear them say, "I need my teeth". Regardless, I somewhat get your point, and I stated this, because I couldn't fathom the concept of "kashering" your REAL teeth. False teeth was the only idea that made sense in this context.

Comment: @DanF Gotcha :)

Comment: @DanF I do know that the first ingredient in Shabbos toothpaste used to be sugar

Comment: @SAH I think that may be the main ingredient in many toothpastes. What makes that one "Shabbos" toothpaste and why would the sugar make it permissible on Shabbos? If sugar is the main ingredient in a toothpaste, it would be a huge boon for a dentist to recommend it to kids.

Comment: @SAH If sugar is, in fact, the main ingredient, that would probably place it in the category of "food", which may make it subject to chametz issues.

Comment: @DanF No way! It's only heimish toothpaste that has ever had sugar. "Shabbos" toothpaste , or "tooth wash" as they call it , is liquid. The sugar doesn't have anything to do with its permissibility on Shabbos as far as I know; at any rate, they seem to have removed it. Finally, I think that anyone frum enough to brush their teeth with sugar water would be concerned with chametz in their toothpaste whether or not it contained that (Pesach-friendly) ingredient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Rabbi Yehuda Spitz on Ohr.edu](http://ohr.edu/holidays/pesach/laws_and_customs/5117) based on a letter written by Rabbi Shlomo Zalman Aurbach to the Chazon Ish regarding teeth & dentures any food that remains in the mouth becomes repulsive and Pagum. He goes on to say that it is best not to eat any Chometz 24 hours prior and to drink a hot cup of water prior to Pesach, and that a proper oral cleaning is enough per Halacha.

Comment: "proper oral cleaning" - So, I should go to the dentist on Erev Pesach? Doesn't some fluoride have chametz in it, which is why I see many people buy KP toothpaste?

Comment: @DanF: I have never heard that fluoride is Chametz. A quick look on the internet seems to say that fluoride is fine for Pesach. The only issue I saw was regarding using fluoridated water with Matza as it may make the dough rise quicker. Kosher L'Pesach toothpaste such as ADWE has fluoride in it.

Comment: Your answer can easily be misunderstood meaning that even when only natural teeth such a pressigure is nessisery

Comment: Dont forget that a dovor charif like whisky if you drink during the 24 hours can make it "lishvach"

Comment: I remember something read in Shaare Dura A baal Tosfot have a dream that he eat chamets, after maasse he understand that was because there was chamets in a hole into a tooth

Comment: @newcomer Whisky is alcoholized but not charif, 2- bliot of davar charif are also natlaf after meet leet

Comment: After m'es l'es from drinking or eating them.  @kouty. I was of course referring to before. In other words those that drink dovor charif on erev pesach at a siyum.  Please can you give me some proof that whisky is not dovor charif.  I was always told it was.

Comment: Sorry that is wrong. @kouty.  I am not concerned about chomets that is davar charif. Even if the davar charif is not chomets it prolongs the time and makes the previous natlaf into nosen taam.

Comment: @newcomer In this case you are right

Comment: אותו משקה שעושים במדינת רוסי"א שקורין בארש"ט נראה פשוט דמקרי דבר חריף אפילו אינו מחומץ הרבה עדיין מידי דהוי אחומץ שאינו חזק וכו' (ובה"י כתב בסימן צ"ה דאינו מקרי דבר חריף דיכולין לשתותו כשהוא חי אם לא שהוא כ"כ מחומץ שאינו יכול לשתותו כשהוא חי כמו חומץ ע"ש  https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A6%D7%95_%D7%91